# Installshield :: Launch default browser with url

Tags: window, installshield

Is there any way to launch default browser from intallshield after completing installation?

I followed [installshield 2008 how to open url when install sucessfully completes](http://www.experts-exchange.com/Programming/Installation/Q_25300723.html). but did not understand how to do it.

Do we have any elegant way to do it?

Answer (score 0):

Yes.
Here is what is needed to be done.

> 1. Write a batch file or vbscript that opens the url you want.
> 2. Convert that bat file into an exe using any of the converters available.
> 3. Call that exe via custom action.
> 4. Schedule that custom action after installation completes. i.e. After='InstallFinalize'.

Answer (score 0):

You may also want to detect the default browser which you can do by googling the registry key.
The easiest way to do what you want would be to create the custom action as he said and go to the finish button and add action, choose your custom action and add the condition "NOT INSTALLED", so it only runs when it is installed and not for example while unisntalling.

Here is some sample code.

```
Dim iURL As String
Dim objShell

iURL = "www.happycat.com"

objShell = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
objShell.ShellExecute("C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe", iURL, "", "", 1)
```